# Pagespeed module is renaming iframe

Tags: php, apache, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have Google's page-speed module installed on my server. Now in one of page of my site there are 3 iframes showing content of different page of the same domain (my domain). Now the problem is page-speed is renaming the iframe as pagespeed_iframe when the page is hitted in the server. Any idea how to stop this. Adding ModPagespeed=off is not a preferable option to me though when i tried that the iframe was just fine. Is there any way to stop the renaming process of iframe? Also is there any way to disable page-speed without changing or adding anything to the url?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the functionality of the defer_javascript filter. Is this breaking your page? It should be renaming them temporarily and then turning them back into iframes afterwards. However you can disable it by disabling this filter with "ModPagespeedDisableFilters defer_javascript" in your Apache config.

If you want to disable mod_pagespeed entirely just add "ModPagespeed off" into your Apache config. Or you can uninstall the module, of course.